# LDAP properties in spring, User not found in ADS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, server, ldap

LDAP users in apache directory studio.

[image: LDAP Users - ScreenShot]

When I try to connect to LDAP using this `ldap.properties` file,

```
ldap.host=localhost
ldap.port=10389
ldap.securityProtocol=ldap
ldap.rootContext=DC=example,DC=com
ldap.logonExtension=example.com
ldap.searchFilter=(&(ou=users)(userid=[username]))
ldap.reqEmployeeNoField=CN
ldap.defaultUserPrefix=CN=[username]
ldap.defaultUserName=admin
ldap.defaultPassword=secret
```

I got this error message in my project.

[image: Error message in my project - ScreenShot]

The connection was established using localhost and port 10389, but the error is showing because it can't get the default user from ADS. 
Can anyone tell me if there any problems in `ldap.properties` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search filter is likely wrong. `ou` is a container in LDAP unless you have it in the entry itself and the sample entry you show above does not have a `userid` attribute (but a `uid` or `CN`). So, this is how I would try to change the properties:

```
ldap.rootContext=OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
...
ldap.searchFilter=(CN=[username]))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are right. But sorry to say still its not working.

Comment: Sajeer - does the user have the right privileges? Have you tried any other tool to see if this is Spring related or Active Directory related?